# How do I prevent C# from printing escape character in string?

Tags: c#, escaping

I'm having a hard time figuring this out, it's probably something simple that's under my nose but I can't do it.

I need to add a double quote to a string and if I use the c# escape char it puts it in the string as well.
My code is:

my code: `"\"" + mystring + "\""`

current output: `\"hello\"`

what should be output: `"hello"`

Comment: what is the difference between the current output and the desired output? 
nevertheless, u ca use [@](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) before the string

Comment: Where do you see the output? Is it what `Console.WriteLine` prints?

Comment: " it puts it in the string as well" - I don't believe it does. I believe what you're seeing is the output *in the debugger*. Try printing the value out in the console or something like that... you won't see any backslashes.